# Как в jsfiddle писать на ES6 из под IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ecmascript-6, jsfiddle

писал пример на Babel + JSX, при проверке в IE11 получил ошибку на array function (в IE11 её поддержки нет)

можно ли в IE показывать примеры на ES6 реализованные в  jsfiddle?

если да, то как правильно настроить среду?

`UPDATE`

в IE11 этот пример не не отрисовался:

https://jsfiddle.net/r9sj7rfa/1/

Comment: добавь пример который у тебя работает в одном браузере и не работает в IE

Comment: проблема в `data-presets="es2017,react,stage-0"`, который выставляется автоматически, и пока не видно хоть каких-нибудь настроек позволяющих изменить presets

Comment: то есть на данной площадке, пример reactJS(babel+JSX) в IE работать не должен? и от меня как разработчика ничего не зависит?

Comment: судя по всему - да. Если только нет где-то скрытых настроек, но я не могу их найти пока

Comment: @Grundy, огромное спасибо

Comment: А зачем ты ссылку на нерабочую поменял?

Comment: по личным причинам, это так важно?

Comment: Вандализм даже своих вопросов не приветствуется и будет сделан откат. В любом случае ссылка оставалась в истории изменений. Если ты хотел ее вообще убрать пошли тревогу модераторам с пояснением что и как